# Oracle sequence and cursor

Tags: oracle, cursor, sequence

I am a SQL user and trying to understand the Oracle cursor code below .

I understand that the first block is getting the current sequence number from `id_seq` into `id`  . BUT what is the second block doing ?

Particularly this line -  `IF c3%NOTFOUND OR c3_rec.id IS NULL THEN` what is the meaning of `c3 NOTFOUND` and `c3_rec.id IS NULL`

```
    CURSOR c3 IS
    SELECT id_seq.CURRVAL id
    FROM dual;

OPEN c3;
FETCH c3 INTO c3_rec;
IF c3%NOTFOUND OR c3_rec.id IS NULL THEN
```

Comment: I am no Oracle expert but a very quick google search found this. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems011.htm

Comment: The first block is simply defining the cursor. The second is opening it and fetching the data into c3_rec. If the cursor returned no record or the returned record has no id, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luke's comment is correct. The last line means that if no record is found, or if the value of column id is null then ... etc.

In this particular case, I think that line is redundant. The cursor selects the CURRVAL of the sequence id_seq, which is the value most recently selected in the current session using NEXTVAL.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I only see these possibilities:

1. If id_seq doesn't exist, an exception will be raised as soon as the
   cursor is declared.
2. If id_seq exists, but a valid NEXTVAL has not been referenced in the
   current session, an exception will be raised as soon as the cursor
   is opened. (NEXTVAL won't be valid if it exceeds the sequence's
   MAXVALUE.)
3. If a valid id_seq.NEXTVAL has been referenced in the current
   session, the CURRVAL will  be the most recent valid value of
   NEXTVAL.

If the code executes as far as the last line without falling over, then we already know that a record was found. c3_rec.id is the sum of two integers (the sequence's current value and its increment) so it cannot be null. Hence that line appears redundant to me.

Comment: A sequence is not related to a session, all values are on database level. Well in Oracle 12c you can define sequences on session level, however the default usage is on database level.

Comment: The sequence itself is session-independent, but sequence.CURRVAL is not. If my session gets a NEXTVAL of 1, then your session gets four more NEXTVALs from the same sequence, your CURRVAL will be 5, my CURRVAL will still be 1. Both of our NEXTVALs will be 6.